# Call a function using NSTimer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging, nstimer

So as the code shown below, the function loadView 3 is supposed to run 300 seconds(5 minutes) after the user tapped the button. But when I build and run, it does not. I also did a few experiments, I changed the timer to 5 seconds, it worked. So after the app is suspended from iOS system, the NSTimer doesn't run anymore? So what's the problem, how can I fix it?

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(300, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loadView3), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)    
    createLocalNotification()
}

func createLocalNotification() {
    let localnotification = UILocalNotification()
    localnotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 300)
    localnotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localnotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localnotification.alertBody = "Hello!"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localnotification)
}

func loadView3() {
    label.text = "e89saa"
}
```

Comment: NSTimers don't run when your app is in the background unless you have a background task request (limit of less than 5 minutes) or your app says that it has background location or music service.  If your app stays foreground for 5 minutes does the timer work properly?

Comment: Yes, timer works properly if app stays foreground. So is there any other way? I just want the view to change after 5 minutes, it doesn't have to be done by NSTimer. But NSTimer is the only method I know right now.

Comment: Is dispatch_after()  work when my app is in the background?

Comment: You need to take a timestamp when the app enters the background and then compare the time when the app re-enters the foreground.  If >5 minutes has passed, update the view.  If <5 minutes restart the timer for the remaining time.  dispatch_after will not work in the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this. The approach is, if timer works proceed with same logic, otherwise (probably app is killed or went to background), save firedDate and update UI before showing controller in method viewWillAppear.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(300, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loadView3), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)    
    createLocalNotification()
}

func createLocalNotification() {
    let localnotification = UILocalNotification()
    localnotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 300)
    localnotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localnotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localnotification.alertBody = "Hello!"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localnotification)

    // save in UserDefaults fireDate
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setObject(localnotification.fireDate, forKey: "firedDate")
    defaults.synchronize()
}

func loadView3() {
    // reset in UserDefaults fireDate
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.removeObjectForKey("firedDate")
    defaults.synchronize()

    label.text = "e89saa"
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) // No need for semicolon

    // retrieve fireDate from UserDefaults
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let fireDate = defaults.objectForKey("firedData")

    // check if we should update UI
    if let _ = fireDate as? NSDate! {
        if currentDate.compare(firedDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending {
            loadView3()
        }
    }
}
```